# Background-image not rendered by browser despite background with an image url was rendered

Tags: html, css

Here is plunker that contains the [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/17jZFcow2flcSsINrr6j?p=preview)

Here is my CSS

```
.test_background {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100px; 
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #550000;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.circular {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
  -moz-border-radius: 150px;
  background: url(http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100% 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -105px;
  display: block;
}
```

We see that the first background color leaks into my image (since I don't want to change the size of the image), I added another background color.

But if I change `.circular`'s `background` to `background-image` and add in another `background-color` the second `background-color` will dominate the entire image. Can background color and image coexist?

Answer (score 1):

Because `background` property set all of background attributes at once. And if you skip some, it just use default.
So `background` property consist of a following subproperties:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

You can set it all at once by issuing it in background property (in order like listed before, and you can skip any property):

```
.circular{
  background: #550000 url("http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg") no-repeat scroll center;
}
```

or do just the same by separate attribute:

```
.circular{
  background-color: #550000;
  background-image: url("http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center;
}
```

You can read more at [http://www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have both.

```
background: #550000; url(http://cdn.sheknows.com/articles/2013/04/Puppy_2.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: So why does specifying image and color overwrite each other?

Comment: It shouldn't if you combine the two in your .circular div. Just add padding where needed and change the shape and size to fit your needs.

Comment: @Kevin Because you using wrong property there, you should use `background-image` for url instead

Comment: The example in this answer contains an error: If you write it all in one line there should be no `;` after the color hex value because all text after the `;` will be ignored....